# Managing categories in iOS

Tags: ios, categories

I was wondering how other people manage categories in iOS?  I just started using them, and I wanted to start building a category on MKMapView for some utility functions that I'd use across some map apps.  I was wondering if there was any best practices for managing a category across projects?  Do most developers just work on their category outside of a specific project, have that file under source control, and then just add it to their project when needed?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: ProTip #0: if you ever use it in more than one app or plan to  opensource it, prefix the category name with a unique 3-letter string.

Comment: I think this link provide some help to understand category use in ios [Here is the link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/objective-c-categories--mobile-10648)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a repo that contains your commonly used Categories that are prefixed like @H2CO3 mentioned.  Link to that manually by pulling them into each new project, or using a more sane solution like a private cocoapod or git submodules.  I recommend looking at this for an idea of how to make a local cocoapod for use as a "toolbox" of categories:
https://coderwall.com/p/7ucsva

Comment: Sorry dumb question, but what does it mean to link manually?  Does that mean only one file exists in my repo for my category, and then multiple projects just reference that one file?  This would be instead of dragging the file into the project and have it "copy to destination folder if needed"?  How do I link manually?  Is that in build settings somewhere?  Thanks.

Comment: By linking manually, I meant that you would create a static library that is linked to your project.  You could also just drag it in and don't check "copy to destination folder if needed".